# White space above navbar in menu overlay

Tags: html, css, space

I have been building an overlay menu which drops down from the top of the page. I want the nav bar to be inside the overlay `( <div id="myNav" class="overlay"> )` which is working but unfortunately there is a white space above it and i cant seem to find where i can get rid of this and it not effect the rest of the site

The link is http://ptdtest.website/home.html

here is the code

Comment: Every element has a default margin and padding, try to remove it

Comment: You have given `top: 4%` which is the reason for white space in the `.overlay-content`

Comment: I tried this and this made the button unresponsive, the menu now doesn't open

Answer (score 0):

```
.overlay-content {
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 4% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    margin-top: 1px !important;
}
```

This css is used in you page you need to remove `top` property from it and new css will be this

```
.overlay-content {
    position: fixed !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    margin-top: 1px !important;
}
```

Top property giving space to your `.overlay-content` from top.

Comment: I tried this and this made the button unresponsive, the menu now doesn't open

Comment: try to post your code or create a fiddle because problem can be rectified only after testing them.

Answer (score 0):

just changing the **top** property of **overlay-content** to **0**

Comment: I tried this and this made the button unresponsive, the menu now doesn't open

Comment: change also your **.overlay** *z-index* to **-1** as default, the overlay was above your header that has z-index of 12. whenever you call your .overlay, changes its z-index to number greater than 12.